# How to include .Net Core 2.0 in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I want to create a project in .Net Core 2.0, but some how the Visual Studio 2017 SDK does not displays the .Net Core 2.0 in Target Framework selection drop down list.

I have already installed .net Core 2.0 SDK on my machine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you use version 15.3 of VS2017? this is required to create .net core 2.0. also make sure you selected the .core workload during setup

Comment: This worked beautifully.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To get [.Net Core 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/) working, you need to make sure you have updated to `Visual Studio 2017 15.3`, selected the [.Net Core Workload during Visual Studio 2017 Setup](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/support/selecting-workloads-visual-studio-2017/):

[image]

and finally installed the [.net Core 2.0 SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.0-download.md).

If you have done all steps, you can create a project with .Net Core 2.0.

Comment: I've got the latest VS 2017 15.3.5 installed (with the workload option you mentioned), and I've re-installed the net core 2.0 sdk separately, but the relevant framework options are still missing for both existing and new projects.  Anyone else still stuck here?

Comment: @Twicetimes can you select other runtimes? sometimes this is completely empty and here you need to repair VS via the VS installer

Comment: I think I've sorted it.  I was being fooled by the other dropdown at the top of the new project template selection which lists all the old .net framework versions.  I assumed there would be a 'net core 2.0' entry on there too.