# Adding .NET Core to prerequisites in visual studio 2017 setup project

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, setup-project

I'm making an application in Visual Studio 2017 using .NET Core 2.1 and I need to create a setup for it. I installed Visual Studio Installer Projects and created the setup project.  I want to add .NET Core to prerequisites so it will be installed along with my app.

When I right click on the setup project and pick properities -> prerequisites I see only different versions of .NET Framework. Is there a manual way of adding the prerequisites to the setup project so that I could attach .NET Core to the setup?

As I mentioned I am using Visual Studio Community 15.9.11 and Visual Studio Installer Projects v0.9.1.

**[UPDATE]**

The app was written using .NET Core 2.1 and I can set it as the target framework. The only place where the .NET Core is not visible is the screen for prerequisites in setup project properities.  [Here is where the .NET Core is missing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzKAw.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include .Net Core 2.0 in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056890/how-to-include-net-core-2-0-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I visited this thread when i was searching for the solution. Anyway thanks for the comment, I updated the question, hopefully it will be more clear now. :)